# Inserting steam user info in db

Tags: php

Im trying to insert the steamid , steam real name . steam name into my db when the user login in my website

mycode :

```
<?php


if (isset($_GET['login'])){

$steamids= $steamprofile['steam_steamid'];
$name = $steamprofile['personaname'];
$real = $steamprofile['realname'];
$ESCAPING_real= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$real);
$ESCAPING_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$name);
$ESCAPING_steamids= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$steamids);

  $query = "INSERT INTO users(steamnid,steamname, steamreal,user_logindate) ";

  $query .= "VALUES('{$steamids}','{$name}', '{$real}', now())";


  $insert_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

  if(!$insert_query){

  die("failed".mysqli_error($connection));




}
}


 ?>



$button = "<a href='?login'><img src='http".(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "s" : "")."://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/public/images/signinthroughsteam/sits_".$button[$buttonstyle].".png'></a>";
```

When the user log in i dont get anything in the db .

i tried to store the user info using sessions and it works but alway duplicate the value

the code is a little bit messy Because im still learning

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$db = array("DB_HOST"=>"localhost","DB_USER"=>"root","DB_PASS"=>"mysql","DB_NAME"=>"databasename",);
foreach ($db as $key => $value)
{
    define($key , $value);
}
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
if (!$connection)
{
    die ('<h1>connecting failed</h1>');

}

if (isset($_GET['login'])){

$steamids= $_GET['steam_steamid'];
$name = $_GET['personaname'];
$real = $_GET['realname'];
$ESCAPING_real= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$real);
$ESCAPING_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$name);
$ESCAPING_steamids= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$steamids);
$query = "INSERT INTO users(steamnid,steamname, steamreal,user_logindate) ";

  $query .= "VALUES('{$steamids}','{$name}', '{$real}', now())";

$insert_query = mysqli_query($connection , $query);
    if ($insert_query) {
        echo "User added";
    }else{
        die("we have error " . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}


 ?>


<form action="" method="GET">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="steam_steamid">Steam ID : </label>
    <input name="steam_steamid" type="text">
</div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="steam_steamid">Personal Name: </label>
    <input name="personaname" type="text">
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="steam_steamid">Real Name: </label>
    <input name="realname" type="text">
    </div><br>

<button type="submit" name="login"><img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded'></button>

</form>
```

check it we have create data base and check my code it work my table user have 
steamid        (varchar  255)
steamname      (varchar 255)
steamreal      (varchar 255)
user_logindate (Date)

Comment: Ur wlc - i just do it For see you working on steam project :)) and u know this 

love dota 2 :))

Answer (score 1):

i don't saw your HTML Form but i added and i think its work check this

```
<?php 

if (isset($_GET['login'])){

$steamids= $_GET['steam_steamid'];
$name = $_GET['personaname'];
$real = $_GET['realname'];
$ESCAPING_real= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$real);
$ESCAPING_name= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$name);
$ESCAPING_steamids= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$steamids);

  $query = "INSERT INTO users(steamnid,steamname, steamreal,user_logindate) ";

  $query .= "VALUES('{$steamids}','{$name}', '{$real}', now())";


  $insert_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

  if(!$insert_query){

  die("failed".mysqli_error($connection));




}

}


 ?>


<form action="" method="GET">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="steam_steamid">Steam ID : </label>
    <input name="steam_steamid" type="text">
</div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="steam_steamid">Personal Name: </label>
    <input name="personaname" type="text">
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="steam_steamid">Real Name: </label>
    <input name="realname" type="text">
    </div><br>
<button type="submit"><img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded'></button>

</form>
```

you can add your src in image tag just copy and paste it in image Tag

Comment: i added another answer u can use it